# GitLab config turn off Let's Encrypt

Tags: gitlab-omnibus

I am installing GitLab Omnibus. I want to use my own wildcard certs. I have installed them in /etc/gitlab/ssl. When I restart Nginx alone:

```
 sudo gitlab-ctl hup nginx
```

my certs are used and I can see them in the browser. However, when I then run reconfigure:

```
 sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
```

it goes and overwrites my certs with new Lets Encrypt ones. I am guessing there is an option to switch off Lets Encrypt completely. I have found this in /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb

```
 # letsencrypt['enable'] = nil
```

but it is commented out - so I am assuming it is just enabled by default? How can I completely disable Lets Encrypt for ever, even when doing a full "reconfigure". Thanks

Answer (score 8):

ok, I figured it out. It appears that Lets Encrypt is enabled by default. To turn it off you need to modify /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb:

find this line:

```
# letsencrypt['enable'] = nil
```

and change to:

```
letsencrypt['enable'] = false
```

note the comment # has been removed. Then when you run:

```
sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
```

your certs will not be overwritten and lets encrypt will not happen :)